# In ISGL3D, can we recognize only one Gesture at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, isgl3d

I am developing an App in ISGL3D. I need to recognise only one Gesture at a time

i.e. either PICNH or PAN..

Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function for recognise only one Gesture at a time:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and `return NO`